# Northwind - Most recent customer ID by employee

Tags: sql, sqlite, northwind

From the Northwind sample database I'm trying to get the OrderID of the most recent order for each employee, what I'm using is:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, MAX(OrderDate) AS OrderDate, COUNT(OrderDate) AS Count, 
    (SELECT OrderID 
     FROM Orders 
     WHERE OrderDate = (SELECT MAX(OrderDate) 
                        FROM Orders)
    ) AS OrderID
FROM Orders
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```

Which returns:

```
EmployeeID  OrderDate       Count   OrderID
1           1997-01-06      29      10443
2           1997-01-22      20      10443
3           1997-02-11      31      10443
4           1997-02-10      40      10443
5           1996-12-27      11      10443
6           1997-02-07      18      10443
7           1997-01-28      14      10443
8           1997-02-12      27      10443
9           1997-01-10      6       10443
```

But the problem is it's just getting the most recent OrderID and showing that for all employees, instead of for each employee. What can I do to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes to you query. Hope It helps.

```
SELECT EmployeeID, MAX(OrderDate) AS OrderDate, COUNT(OrderDate) AS Count, 
    (SELECT MAX(OrderID) 
     FROM Orders 
     WHERE EmployeeID = O.EmployeeID
     ) AS OrderID
FROM Orders O
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```

Comment: Hmm, now that I've looked at it I realized that I need to not be selecting the MAX(OrderID), but the OrderID where its the MAX(OrderDate) for that employee. Because the OrderID I'm using in real data is not an incrementing integer